# adding double quotes dynamically in a string

Tags: php

I am working on a project where I show records on the basis of multiple filters. What I am doing now is to make a `$where` variable which includes all the conditions. For example

`$whereP .= ' and purpose="buy"';`

`$whereP .= ' and type="sale"';`

Similarly for other properties, and then I substr the first `and`. The issue is I have pagination and I can't send `$where` in paramters due to single double quote problem in url. So how I want a solution is, I made two different variables `$where` and `$whereP`.

`$whereP .= and purpose=buy;`

`$whereP .= and type=sale;`

Now when I get `$whereP` from url, I want to add double quotes to values of properties, forexample.

`$where = purpose="buy" and type="sale"`

For this I am replacing `=` with `="` in order to put `"` in front of every property, but how I can add `"` after every property value?

Now I am getting `$whereP = purpose="buy and type="sale`

I need `$whereP = purpose="buy" and type="sale"`

Thanks

Comment: you have to use a pdo and use quote function thats better,this is a wrong practice

Answer (score 1):

You should take the advice in Arun Killu's comment and stop building queries this way, but if you want to keep things as they are, you can use preg_replace like so (assuming the trailing space is a good enough delimiter):

```
$string = preg_replace ( '/=(.*)\s/i' , '="$1" ' , $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better scenario for this..

Create your query string like...

```
?where[purpose]=buy&where[type]=sale
```

You will get an array like -

```
Array
(
    [where] => Array
        (
            [purpose] => buy
            [type] => sale
        )

)
```

Now it will be easier for you to create a `SQL` using this array.

Answer (score 0):

try this sorry for above answer
it will work surely

```
$variable="ad";
$whereP="";
$whereP .= ' and purpose="'.$variable.'"';

echo $whereP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally below but as mentioned there are better ways to do this, I use Zend Framework.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

```
$where = preg_replace('/=(\w+)/', '="$1"', $whereP);
```